# Let $A$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard (order) topology. Then $A$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem: Let $A$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard (order) topology. Then $A$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.**

Below is the way I did it. Kindly check and let me know if this looks good. If not, kindly help me out.

[image]

[image]

Don't worry about 6.29 because that's the converse. Let me know if there is any better style and notation required in my proof. Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: In the $\implies$ direction you have both $A$ and $K$; if they refer to the same set — and it does look as if you may have made an incomplete change from one to the other — then the argument is fine.

Comment: Its A, not K. I hope everything is fine. Let me know if it isnt

Comment: It’s $K$ in three places: the end of the second line of that direction, near the end of the fourth line, and near the beginning of the fifth line.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative proof: In the order topology a space $X$ is compact iff every subset of $X$ has a supremum (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1743735/4280) for a proof). Then note that $[a,b]$ has the order topology too, and indeed every subset has a sup: the empty set has $a$ ($\min(X)$) and every non-empty one has one because of the order completeness of $\Bbb R$, essentially. (Or apply Alexander's subbase lemma directly for $[a,b]$, e.g.) Your bounded closed case in general follows from the fact that is closed in some compact interval.